# How to get the correct URL for an image in Django

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm new to Django and I am trying to build a simple e-commerce application. In this app I want a user to upload a photo of an item which they want to sell. I want to display all the items in the home page, when you hit on the item name it redirects to the item details page. User can add a new item with the following fields title, item image, and a description. I want to show a thumbnail of the uploaded image in the home page near the title and the original image in the item details page, but when I try to do this the image is not appearing in the details page. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from PIL import Image

class Item(models.Model):
    posted_user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    item_discription = models.TextField()
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Item
import re
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SellItemAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_name', 'item_discription', 'item_image')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.item_list, name='item_list'),
url(r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
url(r'^item/new/$',views.item_new, name='item_new'),
url(r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$', views.item_edit, name='item_edit'),
url(r'^item/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.item_remove, name='item_remove'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Item
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import SellItemAddForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def item_list(request):
    items = Item.objects.filter(posted_date__lte=timezone.now())
    return render(request, 'sbApp/item_list.html',{'items': items})

def item_detail(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'sbApp/item_detail.html', {'item': item})

def item_remove(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    item.delete()
    return redirect('item_list')

@login_required
def item_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SellItemAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save(commit=False)
            item.posted_user = request.user
            item.posted_date = timezone.now()
            item.save()
            return redirect('item_detail', pk=item.pk)
    else:
        form = SellItemAddForm()
    return render(request, 'sbApp/new_item.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def item_edit(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SellItemAddForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save(commit=False)
            item.posted_user = request.user
            item.posted_date= timezone.now()
            item.save()
            return redirect('item_detail', pk=item.pk)
    else:
        form = SellItemAddForm(instance=item)
    return render(request, 'sbApp/item_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**item_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'sbApp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="item">


    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'item_remove' pk=item.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'item_edit' pk=item.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    {% endif %}

    <h1>{{ item.item_name }}</h1>
    {% if item.posted_date %}
        <div class="date">
            <p>posted on {{ item.posted_date }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="user_name">
      <p>by {{item.posted_user}}</p>
    </div>
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.item_image.url }}" alt="img">
    <p>{{ item.item_discription|linebreaksbr }}</p>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**item_list.html**

```
{% extends 'sbApp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for item in items %}
 <div class="item">

   <h1><a href="{% url 'item_detail' pk=item.pk%}">{{ item.item_name }}      </a></h1>
  <div class="date">
    <p>posted on: {{ item.posted_date }}</p>
  </div>
  <p>{{ item.discription }}</p>
 <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.item_image.url }}" alt="img">
</div>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: now the URL requesting the image in item_details page is /item/2/media/img/ but the image is located at /media/img/ that is why it generates 404. how can i serve the image in /media/img/ to the item_details page ?

Comment: See my edit to my answer below, I believe that should solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your browser, look at the source code for the template where the `img` tag is, and let us know what is the value of the src attribute? My only guess is you are missing a `/` in there somewhere in the template `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.item_image.url }}`. Assuming the image exists and the MEDIA_URL constant is defined somewhere.

edit:

```
<img src="/{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.item_image.url }}" alt="img">
          ^
```

it sounds like you have formed a relative URL, so one fix would be to make it an absolute URL by adding a `/` as shown above.

Comment: now the URL requesting the image in item_details page is  /item/2/media/img/ but the image is located at /media/img/ that is why it generates 404. how can i serve the image in /media/img/ to the item_details page

Answer (score 1):

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}` you can checkout at template what the output of it, before combined with `{{ item.item_image.url }}`